# Grep: repetition characters in binary mode?

Tags: linux, grep

Consider the following example, where `grep` is used to search in binary mode:

```
$ echo "test blabla test ertytey" | grep -ao tes
tes
tes
```

I can add a 'dot' in the search pattern, to "match any character" and show the next character after the match:

```
$ echo "test blabla test ertytey" | grep -ao tes.
test 
test
```

... or more dots, to match subsequent characters:

```
$ echo "test blabla test ertytey" | grep -ao tes...
test b
test e
```

Let's say now I want to match a number of characters (<s>say 30</s>, no: 3) after the match; and I read from `man grep`: [{n}    The preceding item is matched exactly n times.](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep). So I try:

```
$ echo "test blabla test ertytey" | grep -ao tes.{3}
$
```

... nothing happens;

```
$ echo "test blabla test ertytey" | grep -ao tes.\{3\}
$
```

... nothing happens;

```
$ echo "test blabla test ertytey" | grep -ao tes[.]\{3\}
$
```

... nothing happens;

```
$ echo "test blabla test ertytey" | grep -ao tes\[.\]\{3\}
$
```

... nothing happens.

Any ideas what would the correct syntax be to match "any character" (dot) a given number of times in grep's binary mode?

Many thanks in advance for any answers,
Cheers!

EDIT: as @aix' answer points out, initially I made a mistake of specifying 30 characters to search for, whereas the string in the example is not long enough :) Have now changed it to the more reasonable count of 3 :)

Comment: It is strongly advisable to wrap your pattern in single quotes, to prevent unwanted Bash expansion of certain characters.

Comment: Acknowledged - thanks for that @heltonbiker, good the answers also reflect that; cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, `{30}` matches *exactly* thirty characters, and your string isn't long enough.

Secondly, your grep might require the `-E` flag to enable the extended syntax (mine does).

The following works for me:

```
$ echo "test blabla test ertytey" | grep -aoE 'tes.{20}'
test blabla test ertyte
```

Comment: `egrep` is also sometimes available and equivalent to `grep -E`.

Comment: Yeah, you MUST have at least the designated number of characters in your strig, otherwise it won't match. If you want AT MOST 30 characters, you could use `grep -aoE 'tes.{1,30}'` , which means tes followed by one up-to thirty characters. It is worthy to note that `grep -E` is equivalent to `egrep` .

Comment: Awesome, many thanks for the answer! Also, sorry, I was writing the OP a bit too fast - modified now for correct characters ... Thanks again, all - cheers!

Answer (score 1):

`echo "test blabla test ertytey" | grep -aoE 'tes.{3}l'`